# Best way to loop through array of arrays if Coffescript

Tags: arrays, loops, for-loop, foreach, coffeescript

I have an array like this:

```
[[a, aa], [b, bb], [c, cc]]
```

I want to loop through it in Coffeescript. Actually I want to put those values as attributes for some function:

```
someFunc(a, aa)
```

for one dimensional array I can loop with construction

**for** *value* **in** *array*

However I have no idea how to do it for 2D array. And I wander about the best way to do it.

I'll appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use some [destructuring assignment](http://coffeescript.org/#destructuring):

```
array = [['a', 'aa'], ['b', 'bb'], ['c', 'cc']]
for [arg1, arg2] in array
    # console.log arg1, arg2
    someFunc(arg1, arg2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like `[['a', 'aa'], ['b', 'bb'], ['c', 'cc']]` isn't actually a two dimensional array, there is no such thing in JavaScript or CoffeeScript. That's actually an array of arrays. So if you do this:

```
array = [['a', 'aa'], ['b', 'bb'], ['c', 'cc']]
for value in array
    #...
```

then `value` will be `['a', 'aa']`, `['b', 'bb']`, and finally `['c', 'cc']` inside the loop body. Then you could say:

```
array = [['a', 'aa'], ['b', 'bb'], ['c', 'cc']]
for value in array
    someFunc(value[0], value[1])
```

or you could use a [splat](http://coffeescript.org/#splats) to unpack the `value` array automatically:

```
array = [['a', 'aa'], ['b', 'bb'], ['c', 'cc']]
for value in array
    someFunc(value...)
    # ------------^^^
```

That splat is just a hidden [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) call and is equivalent to:

```
someFunc.apply(null, value)
```

If you need to iterate over `value` then you'd just throw another loop in:

```
array = [['a', 'aa'], ['b', 'bb'], ['c', 'cc']]
for value in array
    for e in value
        # do things with `e`, it will be 'a', 'aa', 'b', ...
```